# Canvas js how to push data from database to chart in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, yii2-advanced-app, canvasjs

I am working on `yii2`. I have installed the canvas js library, tried to run the sample chart example. Now I want to push data from my database. I am able to view single data from my DB, but I want to put all the data when the database is updated i.e. I have a button and on that button click my table is updated during that period I want to update my chart also to show the updated value(s).

**Note:** Chart should show the trend

Below is my controller code from which I am inserting the data into my table

```
public function actionData()
{
    try {
        $cust_met_data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
            "SELECT m.`meter_id` , m.`msn` , 
                  m.`cust_id` , m.`device_id` FROM `mdc_meter_cust_rel` m ")->queryAll();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }

    $slave_id = $cust_met_data[0]['device_id'];
    $address = 0;
    $count = 14;
    $msn = $cust_met_data[0]['msn'];
    $cust_id = $cust_met_data[0]['cust_id'];

    // my base URL
    $api_url = 'https://localhost:44337/api/rtu/GetData/' . $slave_id . '/' . $address . '/' . $count;


    $curl = curl_init($api_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $json = json_decode($curl_response);

    if($json->{0} == '06')
    {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', '
 <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
 <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
 <strong>No Communication! </strong> Meter Data is Unavailable.</div>');

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
    else
    {
        $vol_1 = $json->{0};
        $vol_2 = $json->{1};
        $vol_3 = $json->{2};
        $curr_1 = $json->{3};
        $curr_2 = $json->{4};
        $curr_3 = $json->{5};
        $kwh = $json->{6};

        $model = new MdcmetersData();
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $model->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->device_id = $slave_id;
        $model->msn = $msn;
        $model->cust_id = $cust_id;
        $model->voltage_p1 = $vol_1;
        $model->voltage_p2 = $vol_2;
        $model->voltage_p3 = $vol_3;
        $model->current_p1 = $curr_1;
        $model->current_p2 = $curr_2;
        $model->current_p3 = $curr_3;
        $model->kwh = $kwh;

        if($model->save())
        {
            return $this->redirect(['index', 'model' => $model]);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);

        }

    }




}
```

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<?PHP
  $model = $dataProvider->getModels()[0];
  $model['data_date_time'];

  $dataPoints1 = array(
  array("label"=> $model['data_date_time'], "y"=> $model['kwh']),

  );

 ?>
<div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Get Meter Data', ['data'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>



<script>
window.onload = function () {
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "kWh of Meter"
    },
    legend:{
        cursor: "pointer",
        verticalAlign: "center",
        horizontalAlign: "right",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        name: "kwh",
        indexLabel: "{y}",

        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }
    ]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e){
    e.dataSeries.visible = !(typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible);
    chart.render();
}
};
```

**Chart output**

[image]

It's a single value shown but in actual I have more than one value.

I have searched for the solution but all I found is the traditional way to push data. i.e. in PHP, I have to run a query and then perform an action on that. A sample is shown here [PHP Chart Data from Database](https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/chart-data-from-database/)

How can I do it? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: validate you query that is pulling data for the charts and then validate if you are providing valid json array to the data points

Comment: can yo mark the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting the first record to populate from the `$dataProvider`

```
$model = $dataProvider->getModels()[0];
```

it should be

```
$model = $dataProvider->getModels();
```

Apart from it I would keep things simple and pull the data by making a separate static function in the model and call it from the controller and pass the data on to the view to the charts to display.

Answer (score 1):

You're only asking for the first record. You will need to get all of them.

Easiest solution is:

```
<?PHP
  // final data array
  $dataPoints1 = [];
  // loop through dataprovider for every $model
  forech(dataProvider->getModels() as $index => $model) {
    // data gets added to specific keys 
    $array['label'] = $model['data_date_time'];
    $array['y'] = $model['kwh'];
    // for every $model a sub array gets added
    $dataPoints1[$index] = $array;
  }
 ?>
```

But it's not pretty.